docker-compose failed when pulling images (such as Python:3.10 or node:18.17)
When trying to build with docker-compose up --build -d I constantly get a timeout with the following type of error :
failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: node:18.17: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.17: failed to authorize: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp [ipv6 adresse]:443: i/o timeout

The timeout always occur at 180 sec.
Currently my Dockerfile looks like this :
FROM node:18.17 AS nodebase
FROM python:3.10
...
...

Assuming I would only have FROM python:3.10 I would get the same kind of error.
So far the only solution I found was to manualy fetch the image using docker pull node:18.17
I tried several things :

Forbid ipv6 connectivity which doesn't change anything (except having an ipv4 address in the error message)
Forcing a dns in Docker Engine
Deactivating or activating builkit in Docker Engine as per these posts Docker build: failed to fetch oauth token for openjdk? or https://forums.docker.com/t/error-failed-to-authorize-failed-to-fetch-oauth-token-post-https-auth-docker-io-token-dial-tcp-lookup-auth-docker-io-on-172-18-16-1-read-udp-172-18-16-50-47159-172-18-16-1-i-o-timeout/139461
Execute the command while being logged in or logged off in Docker app
Trying & failing to change the timeout using $env:DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT = "300" and $env:COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT = "300" thanks to some useless advise from GPT4 (timeout stayed at 180 sec)

Any advise on the error ?
Cheers

Authorization helped me:
docker login --username <YOUR_USERNAME>

https://docs.docker.com/security/for-developers/access-tokens/
